# How do I reach a sender's parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cell

I have a button inside a custom cell. When tapped the button presents a view via a modal segue.

So, here's my question, in the prepareForSegue:sender: I want to pull the indexPath of the cell which contains that button(sender) that I pushed. How do I get that cell's indexPath?

I thought I could do something like:

```
UITableViewCell * cell = sender.parent
```

Obviously it doesn't work that way.

Please help me out.

**UPDATE** Thanks to @rmaddy I've tried `[[sender superview] superview]` and got to the cell in which the button was held and to it's indexPath. Thanks for your answers guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `sender` is a `UIVIew` of some sort (such as a `UIButton`), then:

```
UIView *parentView = [(UIView *)sender superview];
```

If you are positive that the button's superview is the table cell then you can do:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[(UIView *)sender superview];
```

Once you have the cell, use the table view's `indexPathForCell:` method.

Keep in mind that if you actually added the button to the cell's `contentView` or some other subview of the cell, then getting the cell from the button is a bit trickier.

Comment: I've tried the method you (and other guys) described above, but it doesn't work. indexPath.row returns as 0 regardless in which cell I tap the button. 

"Keep in mind that if you actually added the button to the cell's contentView or some other subview of the cell, then getting the cell from the button is a bit trickier." I'm not sure if that is the case. I simply dragged that button over to my custom cell in IB. Could you develop a bit on this?

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code. Verify the cell you are getting is the correct cell (and not nil).

Comment: I'm guessing that is the problem. I'm not getting any cell for some reason. I'm getting 0 all the time when I use NSLog on that indexPath.row

Comment: But what do you get for `cell`? Is it really the table cell or some other view?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that. Logically, since I'm calling the superview(my custom cell) of the sender(a UIButton that is inside that custom cell) it should return me that cell. Which I then can use in the indexPathForCell: method. But, it keeps returning me 0. When I rewire the model segue to go from the Accessory View in IB - everything works great (also works when I use the cell selection as the segue trigger)

Comment: But the button may be added to the cell's contentView. Use the debugger or add an `NSLog` and print the result of the call to `superview` and make sure the returned object is really the cell and not some other view.

Comment: I've actually just figured it out with a wild guess :) I did `UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[(UIView *)[sender superview] superview];` In other words, I've reached for the superview of the superview - and it works now! :)

Comment: Which confirms that the button is in the cell's contentView.

Comment: Yes, if wasn't for your tip, I wouldn't have found it. Thanks rmaddy, you've saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

You can access a view's superview with the `superview` property so

```
sender.superview
```

Comment: This only answers half of the question.

Comment: I read the question as he didn't know how to get the sender's parent view and if he knew how to do that he could figure out the rest.

Comment: He specifically asks "How do I get that cell's indexPath?".

Comment: @rmaddy is right. My real problem is how to get that indexPath, because as I've found out, sender.superview doesn't cut it

Answer (score 0):

Just add in cellForRow... method

```
cellButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

and get it back when this button is pressed or you have the reference of the button

Comment: Basing button tags on indexPaths fails when the table allows for rows to be inserted and/or deleted.

Comment: @rmaddy yes you are right. But it's a nice solution if you don't insert/delete row/rows.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is convenient.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell*)[btn superview];
NSIndexPath *indx = [myTable indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden element added to the cell: `UITableViewCellScrollView`. `UITableViewCellScrollView` is added between the `UITableViewCell` and the content view. The first sender superview will return an `UIView` object corresponding the content view. The second superview will return an `UITableViewCellScrollView` and the third superview will return `UITableViewCell`. Then use the `indexPathForCell` method to get the cell's index.

```
UITableViewCell *cellView = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cellView];
```